# Modern article document classes: is KOMA-Script up to date for 2022 LaTeX use?

Tags: koma-script, document-classes, article

I've been reading https://texdoc.org/serve/l2tabuen/0 which mentions obsolete commands and packages, but it was written in 2007 and I'm wondering how up to date it is - most notably I'm looking at 1.2 Modifying page layout, where they suggest using KOMA-script for a smaller more "European" typography settings as opposed to changing values yourself or using the default article class. This seems wise, and I think I see the benefit of using packages as opposed to editing the values myself (as I have no experience or particular need for very specific formatting)

Are KOMA-script and typearea still up to date packages to use, or have they become obsolete and replaced by other packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KOMA-Script and typearea are up-to-date, and not at all obsolete. [KOMA-Script has had 5 updates in the past 2 years.](https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/pkg/koma-script)

A quote from [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf):

> With KOMA-Script 3.36 a phase of major rebuilds of the sources of KOMA-Script was initiated.
>
> [...]
>
> Due to the problems with the finiteness of a single developer’s time already explained in the preface to KOMA-Script 3.28, I will therefore continue to concentrate on bug fixing, the necessary reorganisation of the sources and compatibility with new LaTeX kernel versions in the future. [...] By largely abstaining from new functions, the effort for documenting them naturally also
> dwindles.
>
> [...]
>
> They have also tolerated it for more than 25 years, when I am again not approachable, because I am completely lost in KOMA-Script or some LaTeX
> problems. The fact that I can afford to invest an incredible amount of time in such a project is entirely thanks to my wife.
>
> — Markus Kohm, Neckarhausen in May 2022.

So no major new features are planned for KOMA-Script, but it is still actively maintained.